# Como executar o teste de Cliente-servidor em C?

Tags: c, linux, servidor, redes

Estou estudando o básico de redes e preciso rodar o seguinte código para visualizar como ocorre a comunicação. Compilo ambos, no terminal do Linux, mas ao executar nada acontece.

É necessário alterar algo no código, ou passar algum parâmetro na execução? 
Já pesquisei muito mas não encontro como posso fazer isso.

Arquivo `cliente.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <fcntl.h> // for open
#include <unistd.h> // for close


#define SERVER_PORT 5432
#define MAX_LINE 256

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;

    struct hostent *hp;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    /* The sockaddr_in structure is used to store addresses for the internet 
        protocol family. Values of this type must be cast to struct             sockaddr for use with the socket interfaces defined in this             document. 

    sa_family_t    sin_family
    in_port_t      sin_port
    struct in_addr sin_addr
    unsigned char  sin_zero[8]

    */ 

    char *host;
    char buf[MAX_LINE];
    int s;
    int len;

    if (argc == 2) {
        host = argv[1];
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: simplex-talk host\n");
    exit(1);
    }

    /* translate host name into peerâ€™s IP address */
    hp = gethostbyname(host);
    if (!hp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "simplex-talk: unknown host: %s\n", host);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* build address data structure */
    bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin)); /* init with zeros */
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy(hp->h_addr, (char *)&sin.sin_addr, hp->h_length);
    sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    /* active open */
    if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: connect");
        close(s);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* main loop: get and send lines of text */
    while (fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
        buf[MAX_LINE-1] = '\0';
        len = strlen(buf) + 1;
        send(s, buf, len, 0);
    }
}
```

Arquivo `servidor.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#define SERVER_PORT 5432
#define MAX_PENDING 5
#define MAX_LINE 256

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h> // for open
#include <unistd.h> // for close
#include <strings.h>

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    char buf[MAX_LINE];
    int len;
    int s, new_s;

    /* build address data structure */
    bzero((char *)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    sin.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    /* setup passive open */
    if ((s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin))) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    listen(s, MAX_PENDING);

    /* wait for connection, then receive and print text */
    while(1) {
        if ((new_s = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len)) < 0) {
        perror("simplex-talk: accept");
        exit(1);
    }
    while (len = recv(new_s, buf, sizeof(buf), 0))
        fputs(buf, stdout);
        close(new_s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Exatamente que erro está acontecendo? Você procurou ler o que o programa faz? Viu que ele pede um parâmetro?

Comment: Tem que passar um parametro quando for executar o `cliente`, se o servidor estiver rodando na mesma maquina tente passar os parametros: `localhost, 127.0.0.1 ou 0.0.0.0`. Se o servidor estiver rodando em outra maquina passe como parametro o IP desta maquina.

Comment: eu passo esses parametros na execução mesmo? ./cliente localhost ?

Comment: @LeilaAparecidadaSilva Isso mesmo